# Is there an agreed UML diagram style for documenting or illustrating the role of (Docker) containers in a system architecture specification?

Tags: docker, architecture, uml, documentation, distributed-computing

I'm planning to draw some UML structure diagrams that illustrate the place of Docker images (or containers, in deployment diagrams) in the overall structure of the software I am architecting.
I'm interested in illustrating the contents of containers, the mapping of network ports and other interfaces and the way multiple containers inter-operate.

My problem space is that of distributed, event-based systems (DEBS), so I expect that most of my containers will have message queues coming in and going out. Another part of my architecture involves the use of an in-memory data grid, which will span across many containers across multiple nodes in a cluster.

How can this be modeled with UML ?  If it can't, is there anything planned in UML to address such distribution issues ?

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are looking for tools to assist your jor ("UML efforts") or if your question is more about how to represent your distributed grid ?

Comment: Hi @Christophe, it's the latter. How to represent.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, component diagrams are indeed an option - although Docker containers themselves are not code, they are more deployment artifacts (deployment diagram?). But thanks for your reference - I was not aware of that site.

Comment: A container (in your case a Docker - sorry I'm not familiar with that tool) IS a piece of software even if you have no access to it's code. Moreover it offers you some interfaces that you use. You present the container as a node stereotyped with <<executionEnvironment>> (note that a node can be nested in another node that is e.g. application server). However on deployment diagram you only present a logic of deployment, not the provided functionalities. To present that you should use component diagram as suggested by @ThomasKilian .

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. It is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you meant @Ister :-)

Comment: I edited the question to take into account OP's comments, so to clarify that it's not opinion based nor a search for tools. The number of upvotes clearly show that it's a valuable question.  I suggest to **reopen** the question in case of other potential answers.

Answer (score 14):

You want to represent docker containers and how they deploy your data grids.  But you also want to show how this is related to your software architecture.

I think you should first have a look a **deployment diagrams**.  These are best suited for representing the execution of your system across hardware and software environments:

- here an [example showing how to represent docker hosts, and images](https://mmorejon.io/en/blog/deployment-diagram-docker-django/) with "nodes" and communication paths
- here an [example showing how to further represent the inside of a node with "artifacts"](http://agilemodeling.com/artifacts/deploymentDiagram.htm) such as for example components, which could represent your data-grid components linked across several nodes, and message queue if it's an independent component.
- here a nice [overview of the notation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html).  Interesting in your case:  you could also show the deployment of a artifact accross several nodes with a dependency arrow to the nodes.  This would make the diagram focusing on how your components are distributed,  keeping artifacts on one side and execution environment on the other, avoid over-inflated 3D node boxes.

The component architecture could then be described in a **component diagram**, as pointed out by [Thomas Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian) in his comment.  For the sake of completeness:  see [here](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/dec04/bell/).

Finally, you could explain the relationship between your high-level independent components and your detailed classes by using the **[composite structure diagram](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/composite-structure-diagrams.html)**.

Comment: Thank you @Christophe - this is useful. I appreciate the time you have taken to answer my question.

Comment: This seems to be the current version of the first link:

https://mmorejon.io/en/blog/deployment-diagram-docker-django/

Comment: @janux thanks for informing about the dead link and the research for the new link. Updated!