# Container and deployment diagram

Tags: uml

I have to model a deployment based on Docker containers. I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270258/is-there-an-agreed-uml-diagram-style-for-documenting-or-illustrating-the-role-of/38300650#38300650) which suggests to use nodes to model Docker containers.

I would prefer to use:

- `Device` for physical machines. It is the only element for physical resource, see 19.5.7.1
- `Node` for virtual machines, which is compliant with the description provided by 19.5.10.1

  > A Node is computational resource upon which artifacts may be deployed for execution
- `ExecutionEnvironment` for Docker containers. It is partially compliant with the description provided by 19.5.8.1

  > An execution environment is a node that offers an execution environment for specific types of components that are
  >   deployed on it in the form of executable artifacts.". Partially because a container may host any types of artifact not specific ones.
- `ExecutionEnvironment` for web server, servlet containers or application servers. This is the usage shown in the specification. See fig 19.12
- `Artifact` for binaries produced by our software forge.

The conclusion from of above is to separate artifacts such as WAR/EAR from Docker containers and to sperate physical or virtual machines from Docker containers.

Is my proposition logically and correct from an UML point of view?

Comment: I guess that yes. I would do it the same way (admittedly not knowing Docker by more than its name).

Comment: Broadly yes. Bear in mind that Device and ExecutionEnvironment are stereotypes of Node, so ultimately the semantics of Node are augmented by additional meanings for these. Personally I'd stereotype a Node with Container and then define that myself if I was in doubt, so that there is no possibility of confusion. Artifact definitely fo binaries.

Comment: @muszeo Worth an answer.

Comment: @muszeo, please see fig 19.11 Device and Execution Environment are subclass of Node, Node generalizes Device and Execution Environment. These are not stereotypes.

Comment: @muszeo, of course defining stereotypes is a solution but it implies to define a profil, and i prefer to avoid to define a profile.

Comment: Ah ok, i’ll take a look. I’ve always thought they were stereotypes since their syntax is a node with a stereotype.

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes, true, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To represent Docker container in a deployment diagram, two options are available:

- To use a as suggested by [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270258/is-there-an-agreed-uml-diagram-style-for-documenting-or-illustrating-the-role-of/38300650#38300650)
- To use an execution environment as suggested by the question

As usual, a more precise option is to define a new stereotype of Node or a new subclass of Node but this option implies to define a profile.