# UML representation of containerized services

Tags: kubernetes, service, microservices, openshift, uml

Almost all diagrams illustrating service solutions on platforms like Kubernetes/OpenShift are not standardized in any way. As there is not much reference material available for UML modeling I would like to ask how to model such a solution.

*Note: The question has been closed with reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38270258/is-there-an-agreed-uml-diagram-style-for-documenting-or-illustrating-the-role-of). The referenced question addresses Docker containers. However, it does not answer (and it doesn't even ask!) how pods (holding such containers) and services (exposing endpoints to the outside of a cloud platform) as well as their multiplicity and nesting in a deployment diagram can be represented.*

Consider the following example (I know that this sequence of two services might have limited practical relevance, but for the sake of simplicity consider it a composite service or something..)

[image: Component view of example]

Assuming that I would like to

- deploy this OrderService to an OpenShift cluster
- deploy the sub services in separate containers
- have the containers in a scalable number of pods
- provide an endpoint using an OpenShift service

does the diagram below make any sense? Is there a better way to distinguish between the OrderService endpoint and the service rendered as a pod? What would you improve?

[image: Deployment view of example]